# I just got one question that I am confused from an interview. "What is the keyword that uses with overloading?"

Tags: java, spring, polymorphism, overloading, keyword

I was in an interview for Java SEDT. The interviewer asked me this question: "What is the keyword that uses with overloading?"

I answered that overloading doesn't need keyword, we can do overloading by creating methods with the same name but different parameters, for example different arguments.
But the interviewer kept asking for the keyword.

Is that any keyword that uses with overloading?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is perfectly correct to the question as stated. The interviewer didn't know what they were talking about.

I think that they were probably mixing up "overloading" (which, as you indicated, does *not* require a keyword) with "overriding" (which does).